# How can I give a border to everything within a div

Tags: css

I have a div that contains `<tr><table>` etc when I try to give it a border so that every cell has a border work. it doesnt give anything a border:

```
#dropDownDiv {
    border-left: thin solid white;
}
```

```
<div id="dropDownDiv">
<tr>
    <td style="text-transform:capitalize;">
        ${bean.multiLineAddress}${bean.postCode}
    </td>
    <td>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Home
                </td>
                <td>
                    ${bean.phoneNumber}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Work
                </td>
                <td>
                    ${bean.phoneNumber_2}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Mobile
                </td>
                <td>
                    ${bean.mobilePhone}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Email
                </td>
                <td>
                    ${bean.emailAddress}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        empty
    </td>
    <td>
        warning
    </td>
    <td Style="text-transform: capitalize;">
        {for warning in bean.Warnings}
        - ${warning}<br>
        {/for}
    </td>   
</tr>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** none of the answers worked

Comment: @user521180 Please provide a short, standalone example (15 lines should be enough). Chances are the problem is actually in a completely different part of your program. Also, "It does not work" is meaningless. Do you see no border at all? Which browser are you using? Additionally, your HTML is invalid. Send it through a validator (like http://validator.w3.org ) and fix the errors first before modifying styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only selected the div, you have to select everything within the div as well:

```
#dropDownDiv,
#dropDownDiv table,
#dropDownDiv tr,
#dropDownDiv td
{
    border-left: thin solid white;
}
```

Or you can use a wildcard:

```
#dropDownDiv *
{
    border-left: thin solid white;
}
```

Which will select absolutely everything inside the div :)

---

Just caught this:

You're missing a table tag:

```
<div id="dropDownDiv">
<tr>
    <td style="text-transform:capitalize;">
```

Change it to:

```
<div id="dropDownDiv">
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="text-transform:capitalize;">
```

You can't have a `<tr>` wothout a `<table>`. Some browsers won't know what to do with it. :)

Comment: Which does not work? It should.. Can you show us the page you're working on?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
#dropDownDiv td {
  border-left: thin solid white;
}
```

which means "give all `td` elements that are descendants of `#dropDownDiv` that border".

Your rows are missing a surrounding `<table>` tag by the way. You need to add that.

Comment: @user did you fix your markup? Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2gueX/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#dropDownDiv td {
  border-left: thin solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to give EVERYTHING a border inside that div (and on that div) you could use:

```
#dropDownDiv,
#dropDownDiv * {
    border-left: thin solid white;
}
```

`border` isn't inherited by default in CSS.

```
#dropDownDiv,
#dropDownDiv td {
    border-left: thin solid white;
}
```

would do the div and all td's inside for example